# how to add background image using a url in css file

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I have trying with background-img prop in css but it's not working and there is no error in my console.

I have attach my code and you can see the path of image.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write something like this:

```
background-image: URL('/assets/profile.jpg');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
background-image: url('path/to/your-image.jpg');
```